# Redraw a Single Shape or Changed Shape Only Instead of All Shapes

Tags: vb.net

Please see the following Code:-

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
          Parallel.ForEach(Segments.OfType(Of Segment),
                            Sub(segment)
                                Try
                                     segment.DrawLine(e.Graphics)
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                End Try
                            End Sub
                            )
    
         Parallel.ForEach(Ellipses.OfType(Of Ellipse),
                            Sub(ellipse)
                                Try
                                     ellipse.DrawEllipse(e.Graphics)
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                End Try
                            End Sub
                            )
     End Sub
```

Where the `Segment` and `Ellipse` are Classes to draw Lines and Oval Shapes, `Segments` and `Ellipses` are the `ListOf` of the object instances each of which is identified by a Unique Name such as `Segment1, Segment2`, ..., `Ellipse1, Ellipse2`...

`PictureBox1` has about 362 Line Segments and about 215 Ellipses, all shapes are of varying color, lengths/diameters.

My question - Where `PictureBox1` has several shapes such as `Segment1, Segment2`, ..., `Ellipse1, Ellipse2` , Is it possible to Redraw only the Changed Shape identified by its unique Name, instead of Redrawing all Shapes? For example, Can only `Segment1` or `Ellipse2` be Redrawn?

Comment: When drawing on a default double-buffered device context, your drawing already updates the region that has changed. You can fine-tune this feature handling a custom [BufferedGraphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics) yourself (see also [Double Buffered Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/double-buffered-graphics) and [Manually Render Buffered Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-manually-render-buffered-graphics)).

Comment: This implies that your drawing classes must be aware of what drawing region a new shape overlaps and invalidate that section of the drawing, then `Render()` the content. Which leads to handling a form of Layers (a rendering utility common to all graphic applications)

Comment: It's something like this: [How to determine when Rectangles overlap or intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62948409/7444103), where you determine what existing shapes a new drawing intersects and you draw those sections only (in the example, the *invalidated* parts are just drawn in a different color)