# How to add a drawing to an already created graphic?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I use multiple panels and draw graphics on them.

Sometimes I need to add some changes to the graphics.

When I clear the panel and redraw everything inside - it works, but causes a flickering effect because all elements actually disappear and are created again.

Here is an example:

```
private void drawStatus() {
    Panel Panel1 = new Panel();
    Panel1.Width = 100;
    Panel1.Height = 100;
    Panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Panel1Paint);
    panelDashboard.Controls.Add(Panel1);
}

private void Panel1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    var g = e.Graphics;
    Pen PenGray = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1F);
    g.DrawRectangle(PenGray, SharedData.X, SharedData.Y, SharedData.W, SharedData.H);
    PenGray.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}
```

My thoughts are that I should fire `PaintEventHandler` again.

`Panel1.Refresh()` works for me, handler fires again, but it clears all panel content.

The question is, is it possible to fire the `PaintEventHandler` again without clearing the existing contents of the panel?

Or maybe there is another way to draw on the panel again.

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you want to use a Panel as canvas, you have to double-buffer it (requires a Custom Control or Reflection), keeping in mind that a Panel is kind of *special* in this context. You'd get better results using a PictureBox or a Custom Control derived from Control -- Use `Invalidate()` instead of `Refresh()` -- Remove `g.Dispose();`

Comment: Don't do this `g.Dispose();`. You don't create the `e.Graphics;` object then you're not responsible for disposing it. The `Panel` is not _DoubleBuffered_ by design as the `PictureBox` and you need to enable that yourself. Just use a `PictureBox` instead to fix the flickering problem. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/14171304) for example if you want to draw list of shapes.

Comment: Thanks, @dr.null. `PictureBox` instead of `Panel` works like a charm.

Comment: And with `Invalidate()` mentioned by @Jimi - there is no flickering at all. Thanks a lot!