Paint Event Practices | createGraphics not working
I am relatively new to C# and Winform, especially the graphics class and the best practice of drawing on a panel. After some research, I found that if I have a paint event I should only be drawing within that event.
Prefix: I already have a paint event that would draw the randomized rectangles on the panel.
My Project: I want to create a sorting visualizer highlighting the current rectangle being accessed to indicate where we are in the sorting process.
private void sortBtn_click(...){
    int numRectangles;
    int[] heights = new int[numRectangles]; // Array to store randomized heights of rectangles
    
    // This loop would be the sorting algorithm I would use however a
    // basic loop is used to test the highlighting of rectangles

        // I want to draw over the current rectangle that already drawn on the panel
    for(int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {
        
    }
}

Problem: I found it easier if I were able to draw a new Rectangle without having to go through the paint event (call invalidate). A method I tried was:
private void sortBtn_Click(...){
    int numRectangles
    int[] heights = new int[numRectangles]; // Array to store randomized heights of rectangles
    Graphics g = panel.createGraphics();
    // Basic loop to test the highlight of rectangles
        // Want to draw over the current rectangle that already drawn on the panel
    for(int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++) {
        Brush myBrush = Brushes.Red;
        g.fillRectangle(...);
    }
}

However, is this bad practice since I already have a paint event? Moreover, this does not seem to paint anything on the panel so either way this method seems invalid.
Two main questions:

Was this bad practice? If so how can I effectively implement my highlighting function through paint events?
Did i correctly implement the createGraphics method? If so how come it wouldn't draw anything on the panel

Any other constructive points besides my two main questions are appreciated. I am fairly new to C# and WInform so I'm open to any advice
I tried using createGarphics() but seemed to not work/draw anything on my panel.

Just to add, the paint event exists because it's called every time the window needs to be redrawn. Yes that's after you've invalidated it, but also e.g. when it's been moved or resized, when something was obscuring it but that's moved, when it's been unminimised, etc. If you're painting manually, you need to store enough information that you can repaint whenever the OS needs you to redraw yourself

See whether this example of drawing overlapping rectangles is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181567/5438626

You have already asked this question; the answer is still same: use the Graphics object provided by the Paint event handler or the OnPaint override to persist your drawings. See the notes here: How to use the Paint event to draw shapes at mouse coordinates and here: How to determine when Rectangles overlap or intersect? -- Also to note that a Panel is not a great drawing surface. You prefer a double-buffered Control, as the PictureBox or a flat (non-System) Label. A Custom Control even better

It would be a much more interesting question if you asked about your actual use case, i.e., what these shapes you're trying to draw should represent, when dealing with a sorting procedure; whether these shapes should give feedback when some steps in the sorting algorithm are performed, without blocking the UI in the meanwhile, or slowing down the correlated sorting procedure


Was this bad practice? If so how can I effectively implement my highlighting function through paint events?

This will not work, whatever you are drawing will be overwritten by the OnPaint method. If you want to do custom painting you need to do it in OnPaint.

I want to create a sorting visualizer highlighting the current rectangle being accessed to indicate where we are in the sorting process.

The correct approach is to use a timer. Each time the timer ticks you do one or more sorting steps, this, as well as the tick frequency should likely be configurable. One reason for this is that sorting a reasonably sized collection is way to fast for us humans to see.
This require you to write the sorting method to keep an explicit state for you to do one step at a time.  One way to do this is to (ab)use iterator blocks to make the compiler transform your sort method into a class. Something like
private IEnumerator<int> enumerator;
private int[] arrayToSort;

public void StartSorting()
{
    arrayToSort = [2, 3, 1, 5];
    enumerator = Sort().GetEnumerator();
}

public void OnTimerTick()
{
    // Run one sorting step
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Invalidate the control
    }
    else
    {
        // Sorting complete
    }
}

public void OnPaint()
{
    // Do painting
}

public IEnumerable<int> Sort()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (IsNotSorted(arrayToSort))
    {
        // place a `yield return` between each sorting step
        // this might be one comparison, one swap, or whatever you want.
        yield return i++;
    }
}

Each time you call enumerator.MoveNext() it will run the Sort-method until the next yield return, and then stop. The compiler will generate a hidden class to keep track of any local variables in the method. You could do something equivalent in many other ways, but I think this is kind of neat.
